# Вычисление table.height в javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно при формировании таблицы переносить ее на другой блок, в случае если она не помещается в предидущий. Думал сделать это сравнивая высоту таблицы с высотой блока в которой она расспологается, но `table.style.height` выдает пустое значение. `clientHeight` и `offsetHeight - 0`

Comment: у меня `offsetHeight` вполне работает - http://jsbin.com/cokeyubipu/edit?html,js,output